# MySQL range date from first date result to x days

Tags: php, mysql, date

Sorry if the question title is a little vague, I'm not sure the best way of wording it.

The columns in my query are id and date_added

I am wanting to get results from my table and I have a "date range".

Lets say the day range is 5 So if the first row had the date "2013-04-01" then it will show all results from "2012-04-01" up to the "2012-04-06".  The problem is that first date changes regularly.

This is my query right now,  but it isn't working correctly

```
SELECT oh.date_added AS date_shipped, o.date_added FROM oc_order o , oc_order_history oh WHERE o.order_id = oh.order_id AND oh.order_status_id = 3 AND oh.date_added BETWEEN oh.date_added AND DATE_ADD(oh.date_added, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE date BETWEEN {date_added} AND DATE_ADD({date_added}, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: Hi there.  Thanks for the reply.  It doesn't seem to be working however :(  I will make an edit to my code so you can see my exact SQL code.  Thanks